# Beginning Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm having some trouble understanding beginning assembly.
I'm supposed to be writing a program which adds two or subtracts two numbers that are command line arguments.

The problem arises when I call a subroutine.  It seems to change my stack, with no push/pop interaction from me.  Essentially, if i POP off my +/- before any subroutine calls, I can check to see if it is a plus or minus, but after a subroutine call, the same POP would no longer provide me with the +/-.  Is this normal behavior, or should, upon a RET call, my stack be as it was before the CALL statement?

Comment: Are you expected to use nothing but assembly, gaining access to the command line from scratch? (I.e. you have no stub module to link against that makes it somewhat easy to get arguments? What OS is this for?

Comment: Please add some code, describe expected and observed behaviour and try to find a more precise title for the question

Comment: This task is not that great for complete beginners in assembly language, because you have to gain access to the command line, fetch the argument strings, convert numeric strings to their values, etc.  (Rather than conversion to a register-sized machine integer and using a single ADD instruction, I would have more fun: keep the numbers as strings and do the arithmetic using the decimal digits. Add '3' and '8' to make 11, write down the '1' carry the '1', ...). Then output the accumulated digits in reverse to produce the answer. Do you have to support negative numbers?

Comment: This sounds like homework; if so, please tag it as such.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as the status of the stack after returning from a subroutine call, it depends on the calling convention used.  As long as the caller and called agree on how the stack is to be used, all is well -- and if you write both, you can use any convention you want.  If either side is written by someone else, you need to find out what convention was used, and adhere to that.